# How can I sync Endeavour/GNOME ToDo and Google Tasks lists?

Tags: 20.04, sync, google, default-programs

Ubuntu 20.04, working with the default to-do list app, [GNOME Endeavour](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Todo) (formerly known as GNOME ToDo). I've deleted lists on [Google Tasks](https://assistant.google.com/tasks) app, but yet they remain in GNOME ToDo).

Any remedy?

Answer (score 2):

When I add/delete tasks on GNOME Endeavour/ToDo, they are immediately added/deleted on Google Tasks. However, when I add/delete tasks on Google Tasks, they are added/deleted on Endeavour only after I logout from Gnome and log back in. Perhaps it would be a good idea to visit the [GNOME Endeavour GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/Endeavour/-/issues) and suggest the inclusion of a "sync" button and/or a periodic auto-sync feature.

Not sure if this will be useful to you, but in my case I have two lists in GNOME To Do: a locally-stored list and the list from the Google account. The local list is stored in `~/.local/share/evolution/tasks/system/tasks.ics`.

I was able to move tasks from the local list to the Google list using Evolution (simply drag each task from the local list into the Google list). Make sure you back up the 'tasks.ics' file before trying this. I almost lost all of my tasks trying to move tasks from a list to another in Evolution.

The only problem is, Google Tasks does not record priority information, so all priority information from the local list is lost when you move it to the Google account list.

Comment: You could vote [this Endeavour issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/Endeavour/-/issues/410) about a sync button